# getting Syntax error on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript

I am trying to follow tutorial on how to display WebViewer for pdf. However I get this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of const docViewerindex.html:23:14note: Previously declared at line 20, column 12index.html:20:12
```

I can see that there is wrong redeclaration however I I am new to this and I have no idea how to fix it. Can someone please advise, I am completely new to this

Based on this
I had a look on this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Redeclared_parameter and. tried to change const to let but that still doesn't help

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Basic WebViewer</title>
    </head>
    
    <!-- Import WebViewer as a script tag -->
    <script src='WebViewer/lib/webviewer.min.js'></script>
    
    <body>
      <div id='viewer' style='width: 1024px; height: 600px; margin: 0 auto;'></div>
      <script>
        WebViewer({
          path: 'WebViewer/lib', // path to the PDFTron 'lib' folder on your server
          licenseKey: 'Insert commercial license key here after purchase',
          initialDoc: 'https://pdftron.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/pl/webviewer-demo.pdf',
          // initialDoc: '/path/to/my/file.pdf', // You can also use documents on your server
        }, document.getElementById('viewer'))
        .then(instance => {
          const docViewer = instance.docViewer;
          const annotManager = instance.annotManager;
          docViewer.on('documentLoaded', () => {});
        });
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the is what solved it

```
.then(instance => {const { docViewer, annotManager } = instance;
    docViewer.on('documentLoaded', () => {});
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
.then(instance => {
          const annotManager = instance.annotManager;
          instance.docViewer.on('documentLoaded', () => {});
        });
```